# to check ram utilization by an executable when called using command prompt

Tags: windows-7, memory, command-prompt

I have created an executable which takes just 5 ms to execute.I want to know the RAM utilized during the execution of this executable.I am calling the exe from command prompt to execute.I tried using  Task manager but i can't find it since the process is not running continuously.Please help me with this.Thank you

Comment: I suggest you move this question to StackOverflow, as I feel that you should capture the memory usage of your program in the program itself (with your special requirement of the exe only being run for 5 ms)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Sysinternals Process Dump, and set it to trigger at increasing threshholds of memory use: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sysinternals' ProcMon.
Configure it to monitor only your executable:
[image]

run the exe, stop the monitoring (otherwise it might keep taking more virtual memory), and than you can check the statistics on it:
[image]

Click on "Details" for more specific details.

Comment: Thank you..It is really helpful.I got the commit peak value as 9.87Mb and working set value as 11.5 Mb.which of these two represent the RAM uses by the process??

Comment: Working set refers to the RAM and commit refers to the page file.